# iOS: retrieve score from Google Play Game Services

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have my code like this to retrieve score of the current player:

```
int iOSHelper::retrieveScore(){
if(!gameServicesIsSignedIn())
    return 0;
__block int score=0;
[GPGPlayer localPlayerWithCompletionHandler:^(GPGPlayer *player, NSError *error) {
    if (!error){
        GPGLeaderboard *myLeaderboard = [GPGLeaderboard leaderboardWithId:@LEADERBOARD_ID];
        myLeaderboard.social = YES;
        myLeaderboard.timeScope = GPGLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;
        [myLeaderboard loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {
            if (!error){
                for (GPGScore *nextScore in scores) {
                    if ([player.playerId isEqualToString:nextScore.player.playerId]){
                        score = static_cast<int>(nextScore.value);
                        NSLog(@"has a score of %d", score);
                        break;
                    }

                }

            }
        }];
    }
}];

return score;
}
```

The issue is: if I put the NSLog inside the loop, the score was retrieved correctly. When I put the NSlog outside of the loop, just before "return score;", it showed the score is 0.
Please give me your suggestion to fix this problem. I really appreciate your help.
Many thanks,

Comment: My guess? Your method are asynchronous. It's known "issue". In other words, you go to `return score;` before going inside completionHandler.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind guys,
I was looking around all afternoon and found a solution (maybe not the best but it works for me right now). If you have suggestions that make the code more optimized, I still appreciate your help. Here's the code with modifications:

```
int iOSHelper::retrieveScore(){
if(!gameServicesIsSignedIn())
    return 0;
__block int score=0;
dispatch_semaphore_t sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
[GPGPlayer localPlayerWithCompletionHandler:^(GPGPlayer *player, NSError *error) {
    //if (!error){
    GPGLeaderboard *myLeaderboard = [GPGLeaderboard leaderboardWithId:@LEADERBOARD_ID];
    myLeaderboard.social = YES;
    myLeaderboard.timeScope = GPGLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;
    [myLeaderboard loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {
        if (!error){
            for (GPGScore *nextScore in scores) {
                if ([player.playerId isEqualToString:nextScore.player.playerId]){
                    score = static_cast<int>(nextScore.value);
                    NSLog(@"has a score of %d", score);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem);
    }];

}];
while (dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW)) { [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10]]; }
dispatch_release(sem);
NSLog(@"has a score of %d", score);
return score;

}
```

this time, both of the NSlogs show the same and correct score.